# How do I enable horizontal two-finger scrolling on Deepin?

Tags: touchpad

I have a touchpad on my laptop that supports two-finger scrolling. I checked the Deepin control center for the setting but I can only find natural scrolling. Can I enable horizontal two-finger scrolling in Deepin?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 official. I just installed Deepin alongside the Gnome desktop environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These settings are not in the control center by default. The solution is to edit the setting in the Dconf Editor program. Run the following command:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Ender your password and hit **Enter** or **Return** on your keyboard.

Next, open Dconf Editor either by running `dconf-editor` in the terminal or opening it in the application menu.

Now you need to navigate to `com>deepin>dde>touchpad` and enable the option that says "horiz-scroll-enabled." It should look like this:

[Image of Dconf Editor settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWANu.png)

Now you can use horizontal scrolling!

Comment: It worked thank you! Is there an command to disable/enable touchpad on terminal?

Comment: @Maxwells.c you can use: ``gsettings set com.deepin.dde.touchpad horiz-scroll-enabled true``

Comment: can not find `deepin` under `com` or anywhere else